# Game was resized incorrectly for no apparent reason (GameMaker)

Tags: game-maker, resolution

I exported the game with the following graphics settings:

[image]

OBS - Interpolate colors between pixels would be like a Antiliasing. I do not think it is the cause of the problem, but I will test without and come back with an edit if it is.

I tested the game on a PC with the following settings: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU e8200 @ 2,66GHz 2,66GHz / 4GB RAM / monitor e943Fwsk 18,5'

Checking Keep aspect ratio this should not happen:

[image]

[image]

Talking with the owner of LAN house we discussed that could be because the monitor is very large and the fact that the PC does not have a video card and it is components do not support the size of the monitor. But he did not give me certainly.

Curiosly (or not) this was the only computer that had no version on DirectX. The DirectX was installed together with the game by the game installer itself. If I am not mistaken in version 9, most computers have least version 11.

Comment: I dont get your problem. Is it because the game window is taking the entire screen and not the small one? I think each OS got a different resolution, and in both your game has the same window size

Comment: @Moacir The problem I noticed is the lack of sharpness, in the first image the game seems blurry.